# C++ bit shift operators not working with pointer; showing 'statement has no effect'

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded, embedded-linux

```
*data << 1;
```

I am trying to bit shift the value pointed to by the pointer (uint8_t type). But, when I build the project it is throwing the warning 'statement has no effect'.

How do I resolve this? Or can I ignore this?

(Also, my build process is failing, but I think it's probably due to something else.)

P.S. I am working on an embedded systems project.

Comment: The statement has no effect because its result is not assigned to somewhere.

Comment: you need to show you code if you want help.

Comment: Don't add the C tag to a question about C++ unless it is about the interworking of C and C++, which this is not.

Comment: ”_Also, my build process is failing, but I think it's probably due to something else._". in which case it is irrelevant and should not be mentioned, or it should be a separate question.  If you think it is relevant, you need to describe the behaviour/error, otherwise it is not information anyone can address.

Answer (score 3):

One usually gets "statement has no effect" warnings when writing null statements with no side effects. For example:

```
*data << 1;
```

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
*data <<= 1;
```